# Ejabberd implemention for android

Tags: android, ejabberd

I set up my  ejabberd server but I don't know anything about how to do implement that for andorid also I want to use push notifications.I heard smack library for android I will try it but I am still confused about push notifications.

**How can I use gcm in ejabberd ?**

**Do I need write code in server side ?**

I need a roadmap.